# Table View with buttons inside of UIViewController

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a Table View with cell inside of UIViewController and I want each row to have a button in it.

The reason I am using UIViewController instead of UITableView is because I want to have other stuff in that view instead of the whole screen taken by table view.

problem I am having is I only see one button in the last cell. How I can fix this so each row has button in it?
I was hoping that could use something like this

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var logButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mytableView: UITableView!
    let carLocations = ["Row One", "Row Two", "Row Three"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mytableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return carLocations.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let myCell: UITableViewCell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    myCell.textLabel?.text = carLocations[indexPath.row]
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = " Detailed text"
    logButton.tag = indexPath.row
    // I was hoping that I could use something like this
    // myCell.logButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return myCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Cell this way.

Create a new swift file with subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Assign that class to your cell by selecting your cell and go to `Identity Inspector` and it will look a like:

[image]

And add elements into your cell which you need for example I have added two labels and one button into cell as per your need and cell will look like:

[image]

After that connect outlet of that element into your custom call and your Custom tableview cell class will be:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DetailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Now you can create a custom cell with custom tableview cell class this way in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
let myCell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

And you can assign values to it this way:

```
myCell.titleLbl.text = carLocations[indexPath.row]
myCell.DetailLabel.text = "Detailed Text"
myCell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
```

And final code will be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    myCell.titleLbl.text = carLocations[indexPath.row]
    myCell.DetailLabel.text = "Detailed Text"
    myCell.btn.tag = indexPath.row

    return myCell
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Check [this](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51831418187064014297) sample for more Info.

Comment: Thank you all for the info,
Maybe I am still not 100% sure. I don't want the whole screen be table view cell. I want my table view to take only 1/2 of the screen.  I want to have some other control on top  and bottom of the screen. That is why I originally used UIViewController

Comment: I did same in my example

Answer (score 1):

Drop a UITableViewCell on your tableview. That will give you option to customize your cell's look and feel. Create a new class inheriting from UITableViewCell and add that as a class to your tableview cell. Create outlets from cell to this new file and then use cellForRowAtIndexPath to set the properties of the controls inside your cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CBTableViewCell
    // add self as delegate for tablecell so delegate can call the function defined within
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.title.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Custom Cells to solve this problem...

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomCell

     //Do sth

return cell 

}
```

Your cell:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var Button: UIButton!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very easy: You just drag a UITableView into your view in the size you want. You add a prototype cell to it and then you customise that cell by dragging in labels, etc. You make a new class, which inherits from that UITableViewCell as explained earlier. You also connect the labels and buttons to the class as explained i the other answers. Apple has a very good explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) Go to the section where they explain how to customise the cell.