# Getting images above cell in a Table view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view which works like I want it to but I want to add an image above it. I managed to get an image left of it which I have found a lot on google of but I couldn't find anywhere how to position such an image. This is what I currently have (same image repeated):

[image]

The code I used for this in cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
        var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "bg-hail")!
        println("The loaded image: \(image)")
        cell.imageView!.image = image
```

But what I actually need is this:

[image]

So I need an image in the cell on top and if possible padding too. I couldn't find information on this anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you add a UIImageView as a subview in your cell and then set images to it from your project or from internet? You will have to design the cell as per your needs i.e. use a custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

This design could be achieved by using CustomTableViewCell in your tableView

Use this Tutorial use `UIImage` instead of `UILabel` provided in this Tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

.It Will Help Thanks.

Comment: This tutorial is not for Swift unfortunately.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift use this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom cells to solve this problem.

Build your custom cell in your interface builder and then set everything in your code.

For more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438754/4906484

Comment: Here is also a tutorial: http://shrikar.com/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks I will check them out!